# No se encuentra el recurso?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Error de servidor en la aplicacion '/'.
Cuando quiero compilar mi app web desde visual studio me aparece ese error en el chrome, como lo puedo solucionar..

Comment: Tendrás que dar algo más de información porque así es imposible que sepamos cuál puede ser el error.

Comment: Bien te explico cuando compila de forma individual las vistas del controlador mvc que tengo lo hacen muy bien, pero cuando intento compilar todo el proyecto me genera ese error y también me dice HTTP 404. El recurso que esta buscando(o una de sus dependencias) se puede haber quitado, cambiado, o no estar disponible temporalmente.

Comment: Eh buscado ayuda en varios foros y recopilado información acerca de este error pero no lo eh podido solucionar probe reiniciar mi servidor IIS, crear el directorio virtual de la app en ese servidor y tampoco me funciono...

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es editar la pregunta y explicar mejor el error con todos los recursos posibles (código, pantallazos, etc.)